# Add part of code to a td in jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have a little problem with adding some HTML code using jQuery into a `td` element in an existing `table`. My HTML code is:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td><strong>10</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</tbody>
```

Now I have written this jQuery code to add a tooltip in the cell containing 'Something':

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    if ($(this).find('td').text() == 'Something') {
        $(this).html('<td><a class="tooltips" title="bla bla bla bla">Something</a></td>')
    }
});
```

In this case the jQuery function works correctly, I have added a tooltip to my `td` content, but the second `td` element is removed. I have tried using `.find('td:first')` but in any case the second `td` disappears.

Can someone tell me how to write my jQuery code correctly so that the second `td` stays in the page? Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're overwriting all the HTML within the `tr` element, not just replacing the first `td` containing the `Something` text value. Try this instead:

```
$('table td').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == 'Something'){
        $(this).replaceWith('<td><a class="tooltips" title="bla bla bla bla">Something</a></td>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you very much for your answer, i have even used $(this).html('...') and works correctly

Answer (score 1):

You are completely wiping out `<tr>s` contents by accessing it with `$(this)` and using `.html()`.

```
$(this).html( '<td><a class="tooltips" title="bla bla bla bla">Something</a></td>' );
```

So on this line, second `td` is also wiped out. Because you are iterating over each `<tr>`.

You have to iterate through each `<td>`